# Mongoose JS Date field always populates with current date

Tags: mongoose

How do you insert a Date into mongoose aside from the default current timestamp?

```
const Order = new Schema({
  order_date: {type: Date, required: true}, 
  order_subtotal: {type: Number, required: true},
  order_tax: {type: Number, required: true },
});

const OrderModel = mongoose.model('order', Order);

const testOrder = {
  order_subtotal: 55.55,
  order_tax: 5.55,
  order_date: new Date('2018-06-29T04:28:11.532Z'),
};

new OrderModel(testOrder).save();
```

Whenever I run this, the order_date is actually set to whatever the current timestamp happens to be, almost as if I had specified new Date() instead of passing in a properly formatted timestamp.

Am I doing this wrong?  Can anyone else reproduce this behavior?